# Printing character after addition as string in C++

Tags: c++, string, c++14, c++17

I am trying to print `'d'` as string in C++.

```
string s = to_string((char)('a'+ 3));

cout << s << endl;
```

Expected Output: `"d"`

Actual Output: `"100"`

I am unable to understand this behavior. 
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Note that there is no override of [`to_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) that takes a character, which is why your character is promoted to `int`, then that is converted to a string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`std::to_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) is a function to convert *integer* or *floating point* values to strings.  You shouldn't use it in this situation.

Use simply

```
std::cout << 'a' + 3 << std::endl;
```

Or

```
char c = 'a' + 3;
std::cout << c << std::endl;
```

Or if you really want the result to be saved as string:

```
std::string s = std::string{'a' + 3};
std::cout << s << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 5):

What you need is

```
std::string s( 1, 'a'+ 3 );
```

or

```
std::string s;
s +=  'a'+ 3;
```

or for example like

```
std::string s( 1, 'a' );
s.back() +=  3;
```

(there are several ways to get the expected result)

As for this declaration

```
string s = to_string((char)('a'+ 3));
```

then the expression ( char )('a' + 3 ) is implicitly converted to an `int` type (due to integral promotions an the type of the argument of the selected overloaded function std::to_string) that is represented as a string after the call of std::to_string..

Comment: I was expecting ('a' + 3 )  to give the result 'd'.  Is this behavior overrided due to to_string method ?

Comment: @Bhawan: `'a' + 3` is an `int` type. `(char)('a' + 3)` is indeed `'d'` on platforms using ASCII encoding. The point Vlad is making is that there is no overload of `to_string` that takes a `char`; the best one available is the one that takes an `int`.

Comment: @Bhawan The set of the overloaded to_string function convert their argument that has an integer type to a string. SO even you wrote ( char )( 'a' + 3 ) this expression is converted to an integer type according to the selected overloaded function to_string. This function is used to converts numbers to strings.

Comment: Note that `std::string` has an `operator=` that takes a `char`, so `s += 'a' + 3;` can be `s = 'a' + 3;`